# Is there a name for "place where you ask C# tagged posts on StackOverflow"?

Tags: discussion, site-name

How one would refer to "SO C#" portion of the site?

- SO itself is not "forum"
- indeed "SO C#" is not "site"
- not a sub-site...

Why: I've tried to make comment about some post where I tried to refer to "people frequent on {*C# tagged questions on SO*}" and could not come up with reasonable term.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Community"

You'll see the term, "the C# community" used to refer to those people active in that tag.

Comment: +1 - that is probably what I'm looking for.

Comment: "The C# community" usually refers to C# users in general, not something tied to Stack Overflow. When the distinction matters, you could call it "the Stack Overflow C# community".

Answer (score 10):

How about **the [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) tag**?

To refer to the folks participating in those questions, I would use **the [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) users** or Servy's **the [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) community**.

Comment: The "C# tag" doesn't make it clear that you're referring to the people actively participating in that tag.  It implies that you're talking about the tag itself.

Comment: I guess it is an option... I'd like to see a word/sequence.

Comment: How about *"people participating in the C# tag"*? Or *"people active in the C# tag"*?